# What to do when BitsPerSample returns 0(zero)?

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

I am using `Mp3FileReader.Mp3WaveFormat.BitsPerSample` to get number of bits used per sample in a mpeg layer 3 file. Now the codec of that mp3 file is returning zero when asked for BitsPerSample.

Which can happen for some codec.

Now, I need to calculate BytesPerSample for that mp3 file and I can't do it without knowing BitsPerSample.

So,

1. How do I get BitsPerSample for such files?
2. Is there any way around to simply get the BytesPerSample?

Comment: See source : https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/Mp3FileReader.cs  You can use mp3DataLength,bytesPerDecodedFrame, and totalSamples

Comment: MP3 doesn't have a sample bit depth.

Comment: @jdweng that will work if I change the access modifier to public for that variable.

Comment: What about inheriting the class so you do not need to make public?

Comment: @jdweng that will do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitsPerSample` often returns 0 for compressed formats like MP3. It doesn't really make sense due to the way MP3 encodes the audio. You can examine the bits per sample of the PCM that `Mp3FileReader` will decode it to with `mp3FileReader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample`. It will always be 16 though.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 16 when decoded to PCM... you can decode MP3 to whatever bit depth you'd like (with varying degrees of usefulness).

Comment: @Brad yes, but this question is about `Mp3FileReader` in NAudio, and that will always decode to 16 bit PCM

Comment: Ah, fair enough!